# Python : changing the value in print statements

Tags: python

I have two questions:
1) How can the initial value of n be repeated in the for loop so that this initial value n will be printed the first time {n}
2) How can I let {p} in the print statement change from the value 1 to 2 to 3 to ... p

The code in Python:

```
p = int(input("Input a number: "))
n = int(input("Input a number: "))

for i in range(p):

    s = n%p
    v = n - s 
    k = (v//p) - s
    n = k*(p-1)

    s = 'no' if s == 0 else str(s)
    nuts = 'nut' if s == 1 else 'nuts'

    print(f'{n} nuts = {k} nuts for cows#{p} and {s} {nuts} for the snake')
```

Comment: you should use actual variable names to your code as opposed to single letter variables, it will make your code easier to read and thus easier to correct

Answer (score 0):

Print `n` before its value changes. Add `1` to `p` when printing:

```
p = int(input("Input a number: "))
n = int(input("Input a number: "))

for i in range(p):

    s = n % p
    v = n - s 
    k = v // p - s

    s = 'no' if s == 0 else str(s)
    nuts = 'nut' if s == 1 else 'nuts'

    print(f'{n} nuts = {k} nuts for cows#{p+1} and {s} {nuts} for the snake')

    n = k*(p-1)
```

Comment: if s == 1 I have nuts in stead of nut in the print statement. i don't see what is wrong in my code

Comment: It's difficult to say what's wrong with your code, because you didn't say what it's supposed to do. Your variable names don't tell anything about their purpose. You have no comments.

Comment: Everything is ok with the code. Except I am using the variable nuts before assignment and this is wrong. If s == 1 he doesn't print 'nut' but 'nuts' which is not correct. How can I adjust?

Answer (score 0):

p = int(input("Input a number: "))
n = int(input("Input a number: "))

for i in range(1, p+1):

```
s = n%p
v = n - s 
k = (v//p) 

if s == 0: 
    print(f'{n} nuts = {k} nuts for cow#{i} and no nuts for the snake')

if s == 1:
    print(f'{n} nuts = {k} nuts for cow#{i} and 1 nut for the snake')

if s > 1:
    print(f'{n} nuts = {k} nuts for cow#{i} and {s} nuts for the snake')


n = k*(p-1)
```